# Error while using delegate: Invalid token 'void' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, delegates

I am getting this error while declaring a delegate:
"Invalid token 'void' in class, struct, or interface member declaration"

[image]

Can someone suggest a reason for this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `delegate` instead of `Delegate`

```
 public delegate void ShowDel(string msg);
```

> The Delegate class is the base class for delegate types. However, only
>   the system and compilers can derive explicitly from the Delegate class
>   or from the MulticastDelegate class. It is also not permissible to
>   derive a new type from a delegate type. The Delegate class is not
>   considered a delegate type; it is a class used to derive delegate
>   types. Most languages implement a delegate keyword, and compilers for
>   those languages are able to derive from the MulticastDelegate class;
>   therefore, users should use the delegate keyword provided by the
>   language. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx)

Comment: +1 [Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9xy7dsh.aspx) is type used to represent delegates.

Comment: got it, just did a small mistake. I guess some time we just miss small stuff.